# Image not showing when URL is inputted

Tags: php, html

So, you know how you make a image uploading system with InfinityFree PHP hosting?
Well, I made one but it has a problem. When I get the image and paste the link in like example Discord Chat, it does not show as a Image, it just shows the link. I saw somebody use InfinityFree and pasted the link, but it works! I don't know how to make happen. Please Help

```
Coding: HTML CODE
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          Select image to upload:
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
          <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>
        
        </body>
        </html>
    
    PHP code: 
    
        <?php
        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . uniqid("", false));
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
          $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
          if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
          } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
          }
        
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
          echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
          $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
          echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
          $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
          echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
          } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
          }
        }
        ?>
    
    Anyone know how to help?
```

Comment: If you upload an image, can you then open/show it in the browser through the URL?

Comment: You don't seem to give the uploaded files any file extensions? Try adding proper file extensions to the filenames and try

Comment: Please give us an example URL that you have uploaded.

Comment: wdym an example of the URl I uploaded?